# Malformed line 52

Tags: 18.04

I dont know why it's saying Ubuntu 16.04.3 when in the about section it says that I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I can't update to Ubuntu 19 because it says there's a malformed entry:

> ```
> E: Malformed entry 52 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)  
> E: The list of sources could not be read."
> ```

Below is what I get when I run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.cannical.com/ partner
# deb-src http://archive.cannical.com/ partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
```

Comment: I do see invalid lines there; correct them.  I see partner lines without a release reference (thus invalid) so someone has deleted them (ie. incorrectly edited file, or ran a script to edit the file without ensuring it was valid).

Comment: I don't understand your references to versions; 16.04 (xenial) is mentioned in comments including your install ISO (20170801) but that doesn't matter. There is no Ubuntu 19  (Ubuntu Core releases use *yy* format as come out once per year, but main releases come out twice so use *yy.mm* format).  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was tested to upgrade to 18.10 (not 19.04/19.10) and will be tested to upgrade to 20.04 in the future, so upgrades to other releases are not tested for, nor officially supported (so as you're stepping outside of tested & supported path, be ready for issues that could occur)

Comment: There is  a typo in line 52. should be "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner".

Comment: @Philipp there's more wrong in that line.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it was helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Here are lines 52-56. Delete the lines 52, 53, and 56.

```
deb http://archive.cannical.com/ partner
# deb-src http://archive.cannical.com/ partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
```

Then go back to the top of the file and delete lines 1 and blank line 2.

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170801)]/ xenial main restricted
```